# google analytics campaign measurement track duplicate install

Tags: google-analytics, installation, duplicates

I'm using google analytics for campaign measurement. Does google track duplicate installs from the same link? I mean if the same user installs-uninstall-installs using the same campaign link,is Google Analytics campaign information updated considering user as a new user?

Comment: This is a good question, but I think it will been counted twice since that are two installations. If the user don't reset his advertising id it will result just one unique user, but I have not any proofs for that.

Comment: good question i want also implementing in my app